# EE 2.7.0: Saving a new channel entry brings error "undefined index"

Tags: ee2, error, entry, saving

Whenever I save new entry I get the following error message.
But the entry is saved. I can open the entry and etdit it. When I save the edited version no error occurs.
What does this error message mean and what can I do to fix it? I started with uninstalling the checkbox fieldtype, since I don´t need it, but this didn´t help.
This error is not channel or custom fieldgroup specific. It comes up for all 3 channels that I have.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: field_id_sitemap__ping_sitemap

Filename: checkboxes/ft.checkboxes.php

Line Number: 80
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: checkboxes/ft.checkboxes.php

Line Number: 80
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/www/deleted_my_path-here/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809
```

Comment: Was this an update to 2.7.0 or a fresh install?

Comment: It´s an Update from 2.6.1

Comment: Now I have a fresh install and the same error comes up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the Sitemap-Module V 2.6 from [PutYourLightsOn](http://www.putyourlightson.net/sitemap-module). This caused the error. When I disable the module all is fine.
The most recent version of this module is 2.6.2. I installed it, but the problem persisted. 
The message

```
Message: Undefined index: field_id_sitemap__ping_sitemap
```

gave me the hint to try to disable the sitemap module.
I will ask the programmer for support.
We sorted it out, it was a bug in EE 2.7.0. I got Sitemap 2.6.3 and this update fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug related to EE version 2.7. I would suggest reporting it to EllisLab on their [**Bug Tracker**](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs) (you must be logged in to see it).

---

Also, Pixel & Tonic offers an alternative EE field for Check Boxes in the [**Field Pack addon**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack).

Comment: I don´t need checkboxes at all, so I disabled the native Checkbox field, but this didn´t help

Comment: Try removing the field files from the EE install. May help... They are located here: /system/expressionengine/modules/

Comment: sorry, can´t finde them there. I thought it´s system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/checkboxes/

Comment: Ican´t remove  the checkboxes-directory under system/expressionengine/fieldtypes  because this will give the following eror:
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load requested field type file: ft.checkboxes.php.
Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory